# Unable to get JPanel components to display on a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I am writing a simple piece of code for class that requires me to implement a `JMenuBar`. I have had no issues getting it to display but I am unable to get a `JPanel` to display on the `JFrame` below the menu.

I have tried this is various ways but I can never get a panel to display. I have tried giving the frame a layout and the panels a layout and it still does not work. All that will display is the `Menu`.  Is this because I am doing this all in a main method? I know that the pros here will be able to figure this out in a few seconds. Thanks.

```
//TestPerson.java 
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;



public class TestPerson{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(600, 600);
        f.setVisible(true);
        JMenuBar pmb = new JMenuBar();
        f.setJMenuBar(pmb);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);


        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu display = new JMenu("Display");
        JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");

        pmb.add(file);
        pmb.add(display);
        pmb.add(edit);

        file.add(new JMenuItem("Open"));
        file.add(new JMenuItem("Save"));

        edit.add(new JMenuItem("Add"));
        edit.add(new JMenuItem("Remove"));
        edit.add(new JMenuItem("Modify"));

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.add(new JLabel("Something"));
        p1.add(new JTextField("Type here"));
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.add(new JLabel("Something New"));
        p2.add(new JTextField("Type here again"));

        f.add(p1);
        f.add(p2);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of the GUI Creation is a little out.

You can refer to this, if you need further insight : [Create JFrame Windows](https://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2Fcomponents%2Fframe.html&ei=lIIyVaHtO-Wa7gbHxIDIAQ&usg=AFQjCNG5UeiNg8itdEUzvvITC-6by0I_QQ&sig2=is5jLedsj1qbegwC1Ca2eg&bvm=bv.91071109,d.bGQ&cad=rja)

I have however fixed your issue. See below for the code: (Tried and Tested)

---

```
//TestPerson.java 
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;



public class TestPerson extends JFrame{

    public TestPerson(){
        super("TestPerson");        


        JMenuBar pmb = new JMenuBar();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setJMenuBar(pmb);
        //this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);


        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu display = new JMenu("Display");
        JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");

        pmb.add(file);
        pmb.add(display);
        pmb.add(edit);

        file.add(new JMenuItem("Open"));
        file.add(new JMenuItem("Save"));

        edit.add(new JMenuItem("Add"));
        edit.add(new JMenuItem("Remove"));
        edit.add(new JMenuItem("Modithisy"));

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.add(new JLabel("Something"));
        p1.add(new JTextField("Type here"));
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.add(new JLabel("Something New"));
        p2.add(new JTextField("Type here again"));

        this.add(p1);
        this.add(p2);

        this.setSize(600, 600);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        new TestPerson();
    }
}
```

---

That should help you.

[image: Proof]

Let me know of the outcome, will you :)

Comment: Thank you. Little confused as to why you renamed file to thisle though. Appreciate the link too. I will read over this. Basically I need to not implement these things in a main method.

Comment: Please elaborate on "File to thisle?" .. Not a problem, I will help answer any questions about the answer.

Comment: I wrote 
    file.add(new JMenuItem("Open")); 

You wrote
    thisile.add(new JMenuItem("Open"));

Comment: Oh, I apologize, I didn't see that. That is a result of me Replacing all the "f" references to "this". I will edit the answer quickly.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I really appreciate it.

Comment: We are here to help. Good luck further

Answer (score 2):

Don't use swing components in the main thread. This is explained in [the swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Add the components to the frame, and only then, make the frame visible.

Don't set the size of the frame. Call `pack()` just before making it visible.

A frame uses a BorderLayout. Adding two panels to the center of the layout won't work: only one will be visible. Learn to use [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

Comment: Thanks JB. I will read over this. I gave the answer to the other guys because he answered just before you. Thanks for the links sir.

Comment: Note that the other answer suffers from some of the problems mentioned in mine. The code might appear to run fine, but it might not, because it doesn't respect the threading rules of swing.